# A "routes-manifest.json" couldn't be found

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#advanced-usage/advanced-node-js-usage/custom-build-step-for-node-js) so that I generate a static file during the vercel build. I've tried moving the files around but it always shows a log like:

`23:41:48.432    $ node ./pages/api/build.js 23:41:48.493    Build time file created successfully! 23:41:48.495    Done in 0.09s. 23:41:48.507    Error: A "routes-manifest.json" couldn't be found. This is normally caused by a misconfiguration in your project.`

Then it links to [this](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/master/errors/now-next-routes-manifest.md). I've checked the issues and everything seems to be fine.

If I remove the `"vercel-build": "node ./pages/api/build.js"` line from package.json, the error disappears. But also the functionality..

my pages/api/index.js file:

```js
const BuiltTime = require('./built-time');
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.send(`
    This Serverless Function was built at ${new Date(BuiltTime)}.
    The current time is ${new Date()}
  `);
};
```

my pages/build.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(
  'pages/api/built-time.js',
  `module.exports = '${new Date()}'`,
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Build time file created successfully!');
  }
);
```

my package.json:

```js
{
...
"scripts":{
    "vercel-build": "node ./pages/api/build.js", 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't use "vercel-build". I just run a script before the build:

```js
// package.json
{
"scripts": {
    "make-q": "node ./build.js",
    "build": "yarn run make-q && next build",
}
```

The build file can't use import or call typescript files (at least for now):

```js
// build.js
const slugify = require('./utils/slugify');
const fs = require('fs');
const qs = slugify('some string');

fs.writeFile(
  'questionsDB.js',
  `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(qs, null, 2)}`,
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file created successfully!');
  }
);
```

Finally, inside the pages/api/test.js:

```js
const db = require('../../db');
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.send(`
    working:
    ${db}
  `);
};
```

Now, if I call `url/api/test` I get the result based on the build.

Things I tried that failed:

- Different node version
- Update nextjs
- remove yarn.lock and build again